# Jquery Animate problems

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

I am using jquery animate to change the size of a div when the content is loaded. This looks good when little bits of text are being loaded but not when a lot of text is being loaded.  Is there a way to make them look the same?

For example: http://www.scotwebtech.co.uk

Click "our services" for lots of text and "portfolio" for a small amount of text.

Comment: I've seen you make *website design* too, right?

Comment: this seems to be the issue of css not the animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be a solution:

use two wrappers for your content:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='content'>
        content here...
    </div>
</div>
```

and stylesheets:

```
.wrapper {overflow:hidden;}
.content {width:473px (static width)}
```

now if you animate the width of wrapper it will look fine.

Comment: when i change the width of the div around the content div, the right of the border is missing

Comment: that's the point, if you don't want to have the ugly wrapping effect, you need to have a "slide" effect that is followed by missing parts during the animation